# How to display data in HTML using Firebase and Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

I want to display a data from database from Firebase, but it's not working. 
I'm using Ionic 3

Code on my TypeScript file.

```
let questionRef= firebase.database().ref().child("Test");
  questionRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
    let question = snapshot.val();
  });
```

HTLM

```
<h4 style="text-align:center;">{{question}}</h4>
```

I tryied to do an alert to show the question and it worked, but the display inside the h4 is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `question` globally and also use `fat arrow function` as shown below.

*.ts*

```
question:string="";

constructor(){

let questionRef= firebase.database().ref().child("Test");
  questionRef.on('value', (snapshot)=>{
    this.question = snapshot.val();
  });
```

}

*.html*

```
<h4 style="text-align:center;">{{question}}</h4>
```